# How do I stop tables in <div>s conflicting with each other?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have been working on a new document recently that requires the regular use of the `<table>` function. To fit as many tables into as small and neat a place as possible, I have been using the `<div>` function. It works well with most browsers, though it regularly causes elements on the document to collide and conflict with each other which is frustrating. 
Is there any way to keep tables fixed in their right places, or alternatively a way to set a specified shape for a browser window?

Here is an example of some of the code I have been using:

```
<div style="float:left">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>...</th>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

When including multiple tables and divs, they begin to conflict with each other when the browser window size is changed, this causes, as easily imaginable, lots of aesthetic problems.

Comment: Can you describe *they begin to conflict with each other*

Comment: "It works well with most browsers": which are the one where it doesn't? Or does it "collide and conflict" everywhere so why do you write that it works? Technically, how are these tables styled? What do you want to achieve? Maybe try to set `display: inline-table` on `table` elements

Comment: Why are you using `float` to begin with? For most all uses, `display: inline-block` is more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Make table wrapper div of fixed width and also for the table too.

```
The possible reason might be because of fixed div width and overflowing table.
You can check upto where the table extends by giving it border.
```

Answer (score 0):

float left property affecting table also.

So give,

```
<div style="float:left">
    <table sytle="clear:left;">
        <tr>
            <th>...</th>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

or else float left to table also